# Flask / sqlalchemy: query inside loop

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a pretty simple worker process which looks like

```
def deploy_daemon():
    while 1:
        time.sleep(1)

        job = Deploy.query.filter_by(status=0).first()

        if job is None:
            continue

        job.status = 1
        db.session.commit()
```

The issue is if a new deploy row comes in it only picks it up if I kill the process and restart it. Is there a way to like expire the cache or whatever see new changes in the Deploy model.

thanks

Comment: I suspect that it is *transaction isolation* at work. when you run the first query in the `session`, a new *transaction* is started. Depending on the isolation scope, your transaction will not see any data updates until you commit or rollback a transaction. To fix it, you can call `session.rollback` just before you run a query.